# guidance with Dj-rest-auth and implementing google login in flutter app

Tags: django, flutter, google-signin, dj-rest-auth

I have a flutter application with a DRF back end. currently using Dj-rest-auth for regular authentication (token).
I'm at a point where I'd like to implement social authentication (specifically Google).

I searched a few resources but still don't quite get the workflow.

https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/pull/336/commits/8f5cc65049c4bcb0c650bde707f5023013497b20

my guess is:

1. you set up your application on google cloud console.
2. You make a request to get an "access token" to the google auth on the Frontend (in my case  flutter)
3. send that access token to your Back end - django to confirm. which then sends back a regular token for authentication?

Any guidance would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is accurate.
The exact flow would be to:

1. Set up API credentials on [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
2. Use [Sign in with google](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) which gives you an object with a token.
3. Use the recieved token to hit your dj-rest-auth endpoint for google authentication and mint your own jwt token and return it.

Now, depending on whether your requirement is for flutter or django I could help better with code referrences for it.